# How can I rotate an AR object in place?

Tags: java, android, arcore, quaternions

I'm try the rotate the AR object in place use `quaternion.axisAngle`, but it's not working.

I just want to make a object rotate in place, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Taoi.jpg).

This is my code.

```
//Right Rotation
ImageButton.OnTouchListener controll_BtnRigntRoation = new ImageButton.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View controllRightDown, MotionEvent event) {
        if (controllRightDown == mRightRoation) {
            ma.initModel();
            for (int i=0; i<ma.infoArray.size(); i++) {
                if (ma.infoArray.get(i).getNode().isSelected()) {
                    int finalI = i;
                    ma.arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> {
                        Quaternion r1 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), frameTime.getStartSeconds()* 180); //y 방향으로는 안됨..
                        ma.infoArray.get(finalI).getNode().setLocalRotation(r1);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use a transformable node - this will allow you do the type of rotation I think you are looking for:

- https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode

Example of use:

```js
           var newAnchorNode:AnchorNode = AnchorNode(newAnchor)
           anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
           var transNode = TransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)

           //Rotate the node - i.e set the direction it is 'looking'
           transNode.setLookDirection(Vector3(0f, xPoint, yPoint), topDirection)

           //Set it's parent to the anchor you created and set
           //the renderable
           transNode.setParent(anchorNode);
           transNode.setRenderable(renderable);
```